# Laravel - How to globally show soft deleted users based on a condition?

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a social network type site where there is the normal front end and an admin interface for me to log into.

I want to be able to exclude all soft deleted records (as it does anyway) from the front end, but in the admin I want them to be included in every query, so I can view them in a list, edit them, etc..

I've tried using a global scope with the withTrashed method, and also tried removing the SoftDeletingScope scope, but neither of them seem to work, it still excludes these models when using the query builder. e.g.

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the user model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{

    parent::boot();

    if ( Auth::user()->isAdmin() ) {

        static::addGlobalScope('showDeleted', function(Builder $builder) {
             $builder->withTrashed();
        });

        // or

         static::addGlobalScope('showDeleted', function(Builder $builder) {
              $builder->removeGlobalScope(SoftDeletingScope::class);
         });

    }

 }
```